# QT app crashs on Ubuntu12.04

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

I have developed QT application with C++ on both Windows & Ubuntu12.04.
I can run my app on Windows but my app crashes on Ubuntu.
So I run my app on gdb and get the following messages.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_GLOBAL__sub_I_SmartEditImp.cpp ()
    at /home/linden/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc/include/QtCore/qrefcount.h:62
62          if (count != -1) // !isStatic
```

I could not specify where error is occured.
Do you have any idea to solve this problem? 
I use QT5.3.1, QtCreator3.1.2 and gcc4.6.1.
Thanks.

Comment: (1) you might want to try using the backtrace command (`bt`) in gdb to get the backtrace of the crash (2) you should probably post some of your code that is relevant to the source code lines referenced in the backtrace

Answer (score 0):

The helper private class `QtPrivate::RefCount` is used for implementation of copy-on-write idiom in all Qt containers (including `QString` and `QByteArray`).

Usage of not valid Qt container instance is the only reason for crash in `QtPrivate::RefCount:ref()` method. For example, that method is called in the first line of body of `QString` copy constructor or `QString` assigment operator:

```
QString::QString(const QString &other);
QString &QString::operator=(const QString &other);
```

So, there are three possible scenarios for such crash:

- the most probable case of accessing by pointer or reference already destroyed object with some Qt container inside;
- dereferencing of never initialized pointer to a Qt container and its usage;
- corrupted application heap by a hidden bug is the least expected scenario, since in that case the application may crash in random places.

Comment: n1le14id9n What was the root cause of the problem? If my assumptions are correct, you can vote up the answer and mark it as “accepted” answer to your question. So, it will be useful for someone who may encounter the same issue in the future.

Comment: The cause of this problem was declaration of constant. I could solved this problem by changing constant to literal.